# osx shell date error

Tags: macos, date

I'm trying to subtract the first day of class (17Feb13 day#47) from the current day (24Feb13 day#55) The command `date +%j` yields 055, instead of 55 so the math errors...

`todayIn=$(date +%j)`................= 055

`firstDay=(47)`..........................= 47

`myVal=$(todayIn-firstDay)`....= error (expecting 8)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it should be enough to just strip the leading zero(es) with:

```
todayIn=$(date '+%j' | sed -e 's/^0*//')
```

Comment: Millimoose, Thank you, that was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Or use `expr`:

```
$ a=$(expr 055 - 5)
$ echo $a
$ 50
```